# pandas: add new column that increment every several rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create a new column in pandas that increments every 5 rows containing specific data (column X) like below

```
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
```

Comment: This would be better with a little more info - what do you mean by 'containing specific data'? do you want this ONLY on the rows that meet a condition?

Comment: this seems to be a question on coding 101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another option:

```
df['new'] = df.index / 5
```

uses odd python 2 division to floor your index. (i'm sure there's a way to do it similarly in 3?)

edit:

```
df['new'] = df.index / 5 + 1
```

works to give you values from 1 instead of 0

python 3 thanks to BusyBee:

```
df['new']= (df.index / 5 + 1).astype(int)
```

---

If you want to start at row x:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': range(50)}, columns=['data'])

x = 23

df['two'] = None

df.loc[x:, 'two'] = df.index[x:] / 5 +1

print df
```

if you want to start at x and then number from 1 you need to subtract x

```
df.loc[x:, 'two'] = (df.index[x:] - x) / 5 +1
```

but I'm not sure this is the best method for that anymore.

you can use `.shift` after you apply it but for some reason you can't shift `df.index` (probably a good reason!)

Comment: df['new']= (df.index / 5 + 1) .astype(int)

Comment: @BusyBee :) I thought it would be something like that, thanks.

Comment: Can we do this shifted? start from row number X?

Comment: @BusyBee see, that's the sort of thing that would have been useful in the question. Offset is fine, more general conditions will start to get hard and you'd probably be better off doing something different. I'll put offset in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with index and `loc` for repeat multiple columns:

Notice - index values have to be unique.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('agb'),
                   'B':[4,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9]})

print (df)
   A  B  C
0  a  4  7
1  g  5  8
2  b  4  9

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(5)].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    A  B  C
0   a  4  7
1   a  4  7
2   a  4  7
3   a  4  7
4   a  4  7
5   g  5  8
6   g  5  8
7   g  5  8
8   g  5  8
9   g  5  8
10  b  4  9
11  b  4  9
12  b  4  9
13  b  4  9
14  b  4  9
```

And if need one column only:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'D': df.A.values.repeat(5)})
print (df)
    D
0   a
1   a
2   a
3   a
4   a
5   g
6   g
7   g
8   g
9   g
10  b
11  b
12  b
13  b
14  b
```

Comment: what if you want a new column on your existing dataframe without changing the shape? (ie, i have 15 rows, i want 1 on the first 5, 2 on the second 5 and 3 of the last 5).

Comment: then need `df = df.loc[df.index.repeat([1,2,3])].reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: for each row need specify repeating.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a python only solution, which could be used for `numpy` or `pandas`:

```
>>> [(x+1) for x in range(3) for _ in range(5)]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

As an example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame([(x+1) for x in range(3) for _ in range(5)])
    0
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   2
6   2
7   2
8   2
9   2
10  3
11  3
12  3
13  3
14  3
```